# Unable to utilise Material UI time picker as it does not satisfy DateTime format

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, typescript, material-ui

******EDIT******
**So I have changed my dataType form DateTime to TimeSpan, and I know this is correct as I have a working MVC version, which already uses this, and the times get posted up in HH:MM format. So the question remains is this a headers problem on my Axios set up, or is this a CORS set up problem on my API?****

I've been banging my head against a wall now for about a day trying to figure out how I am going to get around this problem.

For those of you who have used Material UI, you can use the standard date picker which uses the standard  component, or you can use their special date picker, but for some reason, it's an ugly analog clock, which means my hand is forced to use the native time picker.

The problem I am having is that when I save my form, I am posting up two times, but the format is "HH:MM". My C# .NET 5 API rejects this as it cannot convert that format into a DateTime type.

I have tested on Postman and I get 200 OK if I format the time like: YYYY:MM:DDTHH:MM:SS.
I know this, however, because React is tracking the field value, I cannot create a middleware to format my date like this, as the time picker expects the format to be HH:MM.

I am getting a 415 Unsupported media type error back from my MediatR back end. Can anyone advise?

```
    import React, { ChangeEvent, FormEventHandler, SyntheticEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { Box, Button, Checkbox, FormControlLabel, Modal, Stack, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import AdapterLuxon from '@mui/lab/AdapterLuxon';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker, TimePicker } from '@mui/lab';
import { useStore } from '../../app/stores/store';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { Check } from '@mui/icons-material';

export default observer(function LogForm(){

    const { logStore, userStore } = useStore();
    const { editMode, setEditing, selectedLog, createLog } = logStore;
    const { hourlyRate } = userStore;

    const initialState = selectedLog ?? {
        id: '',
        date: '',
        startTime: '',
        endTime: '',
        hourlyRate: 0,
        totalCharged: 5,
        is_overtime: false
    };

    const [log, setLog] = useState(initialState);
    const [priceOverride, setPriceOverride] = useState(false);

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setLog({
            ...log,
            [name]:value
        });
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        log.startTime = `${log.date}T${log.startTime}:00`;
        log.endTime = `${log.date}T${log.endTime}:00`;
        createLog(log);
    }

    // createLog(date, startTime, finishTime, 8)
    return(
        <Modal
            open={editMode}
            onClose={() => setEditing(false)}
            aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
            >
            <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'white', width: '85%', margin: '5em auto' }}>
                <Box sx={{width: '90%', margin: "0px auto", paddingTop:"1.5em", paddingBottom:"1.5em"}}>
                    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} autoComplete="off">
                        {/* <Formik initialValues={log} onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
                            {({values, handleChange, handleSubmit}) => ( */}

                                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
                                        <Stack spacing={2}>
                                            <Typography variant={"h5"} sx={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>Add Entry</Typography>
                                            <TextField
                                                id="date"
                                                label="Date"
                                                type="date"
                                                name="date"
                                                value={log.date}
                                                InputLabelProps={{
                                                shrink: true,
                                                }}
                                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                            />
                                            <TextField
                                                id="startTime"
                                                label="Start Time"
                                                type="time"
                                                name="startTime"
                                                value={log.startTime}
                                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                                InputLabelProps={{
                                                shrink: true,
                                                }}
                                                inputProps={{
                                                step: 300, // 5 min
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <TextField
                                                id="endTime"
                                                label="End Time"
                                                type="time"
                                                name="endTime"
                                                value={log.endTime}
                                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                                InputLabelProps={{
                                                shrink: true,
                                                }}
                                                inputProps={{
                                                step: 300, // 5 min
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <FormControlLabel label="Override Hourly Price" control={
                                                <Checkbox 
                                                    value={priceOverride}
                                                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                                                        setPriceOverride(newValue.target.checked);
                                                    }}
                                                    name="overridePrice"
                                                />
                                            } />
                                            <TextField id="hourlyRate" label="Hourly Rate" variant="outlined" value={log.hourlyRate} onChange={handleInputChange} disabled={priceOverride ? false : true} name="hourlyRate" />
                                            <Button variant="contained" type="submit" color="success" endIcon={<Check />}>Submit</Button>
                                        </Stack>
                                    </LocalizationProvider>
                            {/* )}
                        </Formik> */}
                    </form>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Modal>
    );
});
```

Anyone got any good ideas or have had experience with this framework??

Comment: Send the date as String, receive it as String in the API, then you can parse as DateTime providing any format in C# using something like DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: Thanks Cristopher, I see what you mean. On my api however, the post parameter is the Type that I an serializi g to (Log). Given this won’t I need to pass a parameter for each property on my Type? This doesn’t seem quite right. I did have a thought where perhaps I can try upgrade my project to .NET 6, and then use the Time type instead of DateTime, although I’m not certain this will work, nor how to upgrade my project haha

Comment: I recommend you provide your API code (controller action and parameters that your action receives)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I’ve fixed it. There’s a few issues which actually were quite unrelated with my topic, so I’m sorry, but this is still useful.

So 1st problem, I needed to specify the [FromBody] attribute in my Controller action parameter. This sets my request up for receiving JSON body.

2nd problem is that the standard serialisation package built into .NET cannot convert a string to a TimeSpan type. To rectify this I had to download the Microsoft Newtonsoft package and add that package in my startup. In doing so the controllers use this serialiser and the parsing happens absolutely fine!

Seems a bit counter intuitive that the built in WebAPI template doesn’t come with the right tools, or perhaps I’m misunderstood something somewhere in the setup process.

Main thing is it’s solved!